# Como puedo obtener el valor mayor con php pdo en tabla mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

si me pueden ayudar gracias, este es mi codigo creo que estoy haciendo algo mal no me devuelve el resultado.
'''

```
$query_maximos =$pdo->prepare("SELECT MAX(temperatura) FROM tb_clima WHERE estado ='1'" );
$query_maximos->execute();
$maximos = $query_maximos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($maximos as $maximo){
$temperatura =$maximo['temperaturae'];
 }
echo $temperatura;
```

'''

Answer (score 2):

Te comento lo siguiente:

- Si tu consulta solo va a devolver un valor máximo entonces conviene le das un alías a dicho cálculo de esta manera:

  ```
   SELECT MAX(temperatura) AS Maxima FROM tb_clima WHERE estado = 1
  ```
- Precisamente por lo anterior considero que el uso de [`fetchAll`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) no sería necesario en estos casos pues solo vas a obtener un número y no un array con N filas de resultados, dado eso entonces puedes sustituirlo por el método [`fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)

  ```
   $valorMaximo = $query_maximos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ```
- De manera que para acceder al valor calculado es tan simple como indicarlo con el alias que dimos en la query así:

  ```
   echo $valorMaximo["Maxima"];
  ```
- Puedes verificar lo que se [almacenó en la variable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php) como producto de la consulta con algo como esto:

  ```
   print_r($valorMaximo);

   Array
   (
       [Maxima] => aqui el valor obtenido
   )
  ```

Comment: muchas gracias ahora mismo lo reviso gracias

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono mil gracias ahora dormire jejeje gracias te estoy muy agradecido

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, no olvides marcarla como aceptada. Un pequeño apunte extra, es que al no estar preparando una query con datos dinámicos, con lo que puedes hacer `query("...")` en vez de `prepare("...")` y prescindir de la linea `$query_maximos->execute();`, ya sea comentandola o borrandola

Comment: Buena respuesta, solamente un pequeño apunte, PDO dispone también de un método [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) para recuperar con mayor facilidad los resultados en este tipo de consultas.